# Is there any possible ways to update (synchronize) localStorage for all opened tabs (browser windows) in React JS (Redux)?

Tags: reactjs

I faced with interesting problem in React JS. I'm opening main page of my application with the list of products. Then I chose few products and open them in separate tabs (browser windows). When I'm starting to work with each tab my localStorage changes (product is added to cart) but only on the current page which I'm working on. Is there any possible ways to update (synchronize) localStorage for all opened tabs (browser windows) in React JS (Redux), not only on current page?

Answer (score 0):

You want to add an event listener using **window.addEventListener('storage', function() {})** and update your application state either using setState or dispatching an action with redux

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('storage', this.handleStorageChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('storage', this.handleStorageChange)
}

handleStorageChange(storageEvt) {
  // setState or dispatch a redux action
  this.setState({
  });
}
```

Comment: I would like to dispatch an action with redux.

Comment: You can just dispatch an action in the `handleStorageChange` to help you update your redux store